# Python POST Request Settings Format

Tags: python, post, request

I am trying to send a POST request with Python to upload a file. I'm converting the following sample code to Python but I'm not familiar with how to set this up.

```
POST /path/to/upload/script HTTP/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: My Client App v1.0
Host:
https://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUpload
Content-type: multipart/form-data;
boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Length: 256
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"
12345678987654321
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";
filename="listings.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
... contents of listings.csv ...
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
```

I think I need to set the headers as follows:

```
headers = {
    "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "User-Agent": "My Client App v1.0",
    "Host": "https://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUpload"
    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data;"
    "Content-Length": "256",
    "Host": "https://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUpload",
    ...
    }
```

Do I need to include these `--THIS_STRING_SEPERATES` strings?

How do I include my token here? The example just sends it alone.

What would be the correct way to format this for a `request.post`?

Thank you.

Comment: `--THIS_STRING_SEPERATES` has to be in body to separete many files.

Comment: if you use module `requests` then you have to use `requests.post(..., files=...)` and you don't have to format it. Doc: [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: I'm not sure but probably you can add `token` as `requests.post(... data={'token': '12345678987654321'}, files= ...)`

Comment: if you use `requests` then after sending data you can check `r.request.headers` and `r.request.body` to see how it was formatted. Eventually you can install proxy server [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) or [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and use it in your request to observer what it sends - how it was formatted.

Comment: When you say "you don't have to format it" can I just use a """string""" to pass the whole request in `requests.post(..., files=...)` ?

Comment: it means you have to assign files to `files=...` and other data to `data=...` in `requests.post(..., files=..., data=...)` and `requests` will do rest - you don't have to create string manually. It will calculate value for `Content-Length`, and it will add `--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES`, and it will add needed headers, etc. You can do all with single line - `requests.post(..., files=..., data=...)`

Comment: Okay. Sidenote: can I use a pandas DataFrame instead of a .csv file for this? Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: `DataFrame` is used only to keep data in memory and edit it - when you want to keep `DataFrame` in file or send it to other computer then you usually save it as `.csv`. So if you ask if you can send `DataFrame` to server instead of `.csv` then question has no sense because `DataFarame` has to save it as `.csv` file to send it to server. But you can use `DataFrame` to edit data and later use `io.StringIO` to create `.csv` in memory instead of saving on disk - and you can send to server this `.csv` in memory.

Comment: I understand. But I can use the dataframe data as json to send it via `data` right? And what exactly do I put in `files` though.I have my headers, my data is json but what goes into files? Really appreciate your help here. If you want to post an answer later I can accept it.

Comment: if server expects `csv` then you can't use `JSON`. If there is documentation for this API then you should check it. Sometimes in documetation for API you can find even code in Python or link to Python module which can do it. In one of previous commend you have link to `requests` documentation and it shows that you put  `filename` and `open(...)` and it will read it from disk, or `filename` and `string_with_data` and then it sends this string.

Comment: ie. `post(url, files={"file": ("listings.csv", open("listings.csv"), "text/csv"), data={"token": "12345678987654321"})`

Comment: Well thanks for your help but it seems like nothing works here but I will keep trying. The doc for the API is here on page 67 , [link](https://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/pdf/us/file_exchange/File_Exchange_Advanced_Instructions.pdf) "Uploading files programmatically". Its very short and not much information.

Comment: well, this document is from 2015, they could change everything few times since 2015

Comment: Maybe there is something newer. In most APIs which I saw there are examples for JavaScript and sometimes for other languages or porgram `curl` . Often there is also tool to test it on web page or you can use it with tools like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

Comment: Haha its worse than that man, I think its from like 2006 or something. Yeah I tried postman but no luck. I will try to PHP it from my VPS, I am not so familiar with python requests.